# How to iterate through custom posts and add the title to an array

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to query some custom posts so that I can iterate through them, extract the title of ecah and add the titles into an array. The reason I am doing this is so that I can then create a select field in woocommerce using the array contents to generate the options (haven't done this bit yet)

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong with this snippet or provide any advice, I can't get it to work. The site goes down and I get nothing in a var_dump

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'custom_checkout_field');

function custom_checkout_field($checkout)

{

$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'pickup-point',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_status'       => 'publish'
    );

// Custom query to pull in the pickup points.
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// Check that we have query results.
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {


    $available_locations = [];

  while ( $query->have_posts() ) {

        $query->the_post();

        array_push($available_locations, the_title());

    }
}

var_dump ($available_locations);

}

// Restore original post data.
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 2):

I see two problems with the code you've written. The first one is that `the_title()` echos the post title although returning the title would be more appropriate in this context. Also `wp_reset_postdata()` should be after the `while` loop inside the `if` statement.

But as you mentioned that you only need the post titles, you can get them directly from the post objects from the query object without setting up the loop with `have_posts()` and `the_post()`. Like so,

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'custom_checkout_field');
function custom_checkout_field($checkout) {

  $args = array(
    'post_type'              => 'pickup-point',
    'posts_per_page'         => -1,
    'post_status'            => 'publish',
    'no_found_rows'          => true, // pagination not needed
    'update_post_meta_cache' => false, // post meta not needed
    'update_post_term_cache' => false, // taxonomy terms not needed
  );
  $query = new WP_Query( $args );

  $titles = array_map( 'get_the_title', $query->posts );
  if ( $titles ) {
    // do something with $titles    
  }

}
```

I added couple of extra parameters to the query `$args`, which make the query a bit more efficient as only post titles are needed.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you need to use [`get_the_title()`](http://%60get_the_title()%60) instead of [`the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/) in your code, as [`the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/) is echoed and can't be set to a variable.

It seems that you want to make your pickup locations (custom post type) to be displayed in a dropdown (or radio buttons) field in WooCommerce checkout page.

You can also simply use `get_posts()` function like:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'custom_checkout_field');

function custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

    $pickup_points = (array) get_posts( array(
        'post_type'         => 'pickup-point',
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'post_status'       => 'publish'
    ) );

    if ( count( $pickup_points ) > 0 ) {

        $available_locations = []; // Initializing

        // Loop though each 'pickup-point' WP_Post object
        foreach ( $pickup_points as $pickup_point ) {
            // Set current post title in the array
            $available_locations[] = $pickup_point->post_title;
        }

        // testing output
        var_dump ($available_locations);
    }
}
```

Or if you keep a `WP_Query`:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'custom_checkout_field');

function custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

    // Custom query to pull in the pickup points.
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'         => 'pickup-point',
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'post_status'       => 'publish'
    ) );

    $available_locations = []; // Initializing

    // Check that we have query results.
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) :

    $available_locations = []; // Initializing

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

    $available_locations[] = get_the_title(); // Set the current title in the array

    endwhile;

    // testing output
    var_dump ($available_locations);

    wp_reset_postdata();

    endif;
}
```

Both should work the same way.

Answer (score 1):

There's a shorter way to get the titles of posts into an array if you use `get_posts()`:

```
$posts = get_posts(
    array(
        'post_type'         => 'pickup-point',
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'post_status'       => 'publish'
    )
);

$titles = array_map( 'get_the_title', $posts );
```

This takes advantage of the fact that you can pass a `WP_Post` object to `get_the_title()` by using `array_map()` to run `get_the_title()` on the results of `get_posts()`, which is an array of `WP_Post` objects.